# Equivalent to getState() method of react-redux in ngrx | Angular 6 | ngrx 6

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, redux, ngrx

I have created an application using react and redux. In which I used getState() to get the state of the store and fetch the particular slice by destruction like this.

```
const { user } = getState();
```

Now I want to move to the application in angular 6. I installed ngrx v6.0. I read the documentation but I didn't find the method of getting the user slice.
However, I think I can achieve the thing by creating a selector like this

```
export const selectUser = (state: AppState) => state.user;
```

But I need to subscribe that selector and get the user state like this.

```
this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectUser)).subscribe(
        user => this.user = user
    )
```

Do I need to create a manual function like below?

```
function getState(store: Store<State>): State {
    let state: State;

    store.take(1).subscribe(s => state = s);

    return state;
}
```

Can someone provide the best solution for this or I miss something?

I am also facing another problem with creating a selector. I dispatch an action with payload userData(which one is coming from API response)
AppComponent@ngOnInit()
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadUserAction(this.userData));

But when I use the user selector for getting user slice of state in the feature module's component
HomeComponent@ngOnInit()

```
this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectUser)).subscribe(
            user => this.user = user //user is same as intial not the updated one.

        )
```

I didn't get the data at once. Always return the initial state.

Do I need to use effects or placing some if conditions?

Can someone explain to me how to perform another action after getting the correct data from the first selector?

Comment: You want to get the data in the component or in the view ?

Comment: in component. I want to modify the data first and set the property value of the component.

Comment: I think we're missing some links here. Your first question is if there's an instant get to the store. Would be better to create another question on why your selector is not working properly and provide more code. Are you using effects for that dispatched action? Do you have only a reducer?

Comment: I am only using reducers till now. Here is the link of another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182646/how-to-get-the-correct-slice-data-using-selectors-for-multiple-pieces-of-state-a

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NgRx has no instant `get()` method to access a slice of your store. I couldn't find it, but there's an issue on GitHub where they said that on the first version they had it, but people weren't using it correctly, so they removed and now you only get Observables.

Your

```js
this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.selectUser)).subscribe(
  user => this.user = user
)
```

is correct. You just gotta remember to unsubscribe from it.

If you can, there's no problem on storing the whole Observable, without having to subscribe on it. Angular has a async pipe so you can easily use Observables on your templates and you can always operate over that Observable and return a new Observable to your required needs.

Ps: It's best to use `createSelector` method.

```
export const selectUser = createSelector(
  selectAppState,
  (state: AppState) => state.user;
);
```

Comment: Now the question is that if I need a single property from the user slice like "user.image" then I need to create the selector for each property.

Comment: I am also facing an issue with selects. I updated the question, please check that.

Comment: Consider my last comment, I'd be glad to help on your new question. Please, provide some code. If you can, place the new question link here so I can try and help you.

Comment: Sure, here is the link of another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182646/how-to-get-the-correct-slice-data-using-selectors-for-multiple-pieces-of-state-a